# Does Keir Starmer fit into the New Labour category?

Tags: united-kingdom, labour-party

"New Labour" was the philosophy of Tony Blair which eliminated Labour's constitutional support for socialized control of industry, favoring market economics and social reform. Since coming to power, Keir Starmer has changed the rules so as to prevent socialists from taking power in the Labour Party. Does he fit into New Labour?

Answer (score 2):

Keir Starmer has not adopted the New Labour nomenclature, nor do any current Labour MPs, so far as I'm aware.

It is deeply associated with Tony Blair - and while many greatly admire and respect Sir Tony (as he is now styled), the latter's name became tarnished by his role in the Iraq war, which prevents the Labour party easily identifying with the Blairite legacy.

Criticism of "Blairism" would come more from the left-wing of the Labour Party, than from the benches opposite.